# Unable to Upload Files of Lightning Flow launched by Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning-out, button-overrides, fileupload, lightning-flow-builder

We are using Visualforce override page for New Case Action that is triggering Lightning Screen Flow via Lightning Out.
The Lightning Runtime in Visualforce Page was Rendered according to [Salesforce Help](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_lightningruntime.htm?_ga=2.200197803.482687469.1691079339-1636543687.1690899133) page.

Page Details:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardController="Case" lightningStylesheets="true">

    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="LightningContainer" class="slds-box slds-p-around_medium" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $Lightning.use("c:NewCaseApp", function() {
            // Create the flow component and set the onstatuschange attribute
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "lightning:flow",
                {
                    "renderMode": "LightningRuntime" // Add the renderMode attribute
                },
                "LightningContainer",
                function (component) {
                    // Set the input variables
                    var inputVariables = [
                        {
                            name: 'Env',
                            type: 'String',
                            value: 'Dev'
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'UserId',
                            type: 'String',
                            value: '{!$User.Id}'
                        }
                    ];

                    // Start an interview in the LightningContainer div and initialize the input variables.
                    component.startFlow("New_Case_Flow", inputVariables);
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

The "NewCaseApp" details are the following:

```
<aura:application access="global" extends="ltng:outApp" description="Application to include the Lightning Component and use in Visualforce">
    <aura:dependency resource="lightning:flow" />
</aura:application>
```

The Lightning Flow contains the File Upload Standard component.
When Flow is launched by clicking "New" Action on Case, the "Upload Files" component is displaying, however when attempting to drop a proper file on it or browse for a component and click "Upload" nothing happens:

[image: File Upload component that is not working properly]

The mentioned Visualforce page is used in Classic and Lightning and there's same behavior - no possibility to Upload Files.
The Lightning Flow that is Launched by Visualforce is also used in Classic for Custom buttons and there is no issue, File Upload works properly.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation), the fileUpload component isn't supported in lightning out.

> This component isn't supported in Lightning Out or standalone apps, and displays as a disabled input.

Comment: I’ve noticed such info on “https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp_fileupload.htm&type=5“ and wonder what could be used to Launch Flow with File upload component by Visualforce instead Lightning Out.

Comment: @VasylPoidynets That would be a good question to ask.  Why not create a new question asking how to do that?

Comment: Thanks @NickCook.